# Any way to solve the 2 Instances of the same App running in Android?

Tags: android, performance

The issue I am having is with multiple app instances running in my Android Phone.
Find below the situation I am stuck up with.

Install any app from Google Play (say, Facebook), and after installing it, click on Open from Google Play in Android device. One instance of the App will be opened.

By clicking Home button of the Android device and navigating to the installed app in the device, we are able to open another instance of the same app in the Android device.

This is an error, as when we close any one app from above, the other will be still running in the device. I need a workaround by which only one instance will be running and the second one should overwrite the first one.

Comment: if it is not your own app, how do you expect to fix it?

Comment: I have my own app and it has the same issue. I mentioned Facebook for an example to be familiar.

Comment: What do you mean "close" with regard to an app?  Apart from the dialog in settings, you can't.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the probably the best way, probably far from being efficient, but let me try this. In your first activity, you can open a database connection or just write to a file, as a proof that application is started, and also check for this file, or database before starting your app. If you find the file or database entry, then simply exit the app. In this case you will only have one working instance. I only assume this that you cannot change the android launcher for the apps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use a launch flag in your activity definition in your manifest.

This post explains the various options available to you.

http://www.intridea.com/blog/2011/6/16/android-understanding-activity-launchmode